# How to access background of grandparent CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I am wondering if it is possible to access the background of the grandparent element and use that as the background. I', not quite sure how to word this, so I'll show what I mean. I am also using SCSS.

```
<body>
    <main>
        <div></div>
    </main>
</body>
```

Just a basic code structure

```
body {
    background-image: url("backround-img.jpg");
    background-attatchment: fixed;
}
main {
    background-color: white;
    div {
        background-color: transparent;
        // I want to have the image of the body as the background image of this div
    }
}
```

I am trying to create the same effect that Instagram DMs have with this. Is this possible without manually setting the background image to each of the divs that I want this background on?

Comment: You can get the grand parent with javascript. Or you put de value of background in variable SCSS and you get in when you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to store the image url inside a [CSS Variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and then reuse it wherever needed. (Sorry for not using SASS but basically the same)

```css
:root {
  --image-1: url(https://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris) ;
}

body {
    background-image: var(--image-1);
    background-attatchment: fixed;

    /* next two line only for demo */
    border: solid 5px orange;
    width: 500px; height: 400px;
}

main {
    background-color: white;
}

main div {
    background-image: var(--image-1);

    /* next two line only for demo */
    border: solid 5px fuchsia;
    width: 300px; height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use inheritance:

```css
<body>
    <main>
        <div></div>
    </main>
</body>



body {
    background-image: url("backround-img.jpg");
    background-attatchment: fixed;
}
main {
    background-color: white;
    background-image:inherit; /* here */
    background-size:0 0; /* cancel the background on main */ 
    div {
        background-image:inherit; /* here */
        background-color: transparent;
        
    }
}
```